# what is the default kernel_initializer in keras

Tags: neural-network, keras

In the user manual, it shows the different kernel_initializer below

https://keras.io/initializers/

the main purpose is to initialize the weight matrix in the neural network.

Anyone knows what the default initializer is? the document didn't show the default.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Usually, it's `glorot_uniform` by default. Different layer types might have different default `kernel_initializer`. When in doubt, just look in the source [code](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/62d097c4ff6fa694a4dbc670e9c7eb9e2bc27c74/keras/layers/core.py#L798). For example, for `Dense` layer:

```
class Dense(Layer):
...
    def __init__(self, units,
                 activation=None,
                 use_bias=True,
                 kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',
                 bias_initializer='zeros',
                 kernel_regularizer=None,
                 bias_regularizer=None,
                 activity_regularizer=None,
                 kernel_constraint=None,
                 bias_constraint=None,
                 **kwargs):
```

Comment: +1 you give a man his answer he solves one problem, you teach a man to read source code, he solves problems everyday.

Comment: There is also `glorot_normal`, but I am reading that uniform is preferred for both glorot and he.

Answer (score 6):

**GlorotUniform**, keras uses Glorot initialization with a uniform distribution.r = √(3/fan_avg)

fan_avg = (fan_in + fan_out) /2

number of inputs = fan_in

number of nurons in a layer = fan_out