# Where to find a documentation about default weight initializer in Keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I just read about the Keras weight initializers in [here](https://keras.io/initializers/). In the documentation, only different initializers has been introduced. Such as:

```
model.add(Dense(64, kernel_initializer='random_normal'))
```

I want to know what is the **default weight** when I don't specify the `kernel_initializer` argument. 
Is there a way to access it?

Comment: The default is glorot initializer. It draws samples from a uniform distribution within [-limit, limit] where limit is sqrt(6 / (fan_in + fan_out)) where fan_in is the number of input units in the weight tensor and fan_out is the number of output units in the weight tensor.

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46883606/what-is-the-default-kernel-initializer-in-keras

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Each layer has its own default value for initializing the weights. For most of the layers, such as `Dense`, convolution and RNN layers, the default kernel initializer is `'glorot_uniform'` and the default bias intializer is `'zeros'` (you can find this by going to the related section for each layer in the documentation; for example [here](https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/dense/) is the Dense layer doc). You can find the definition of `glorot_uniform` initializer [here](https://keras.io/api/layers/initializers/#glorotuniform-class) in the Keras documentation.

As for accessing the weights of each layer, it has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54009163/2099607).

Comment: I think this article is very interesting and it shows roughly that for `"tanh"` activations you should use `'glorot_uniform'` and for `"relu"` layers you should use `"he_uniform"`: https://towardsdatascience.com/weight-initialization-in-neural-networks-a-journey-from-the-basics-to-kaiming-954fb9b47c79

Comment: For embedding layer it says 'uniform' however which uniform? Glorot or he? Cannot find the answer on the documentation.