# How to visualize a keras neural network with trained weights?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, visualization

I have created a sequential model using `keras` package similar to this:

```py
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import Sequential

model = Sequential()

# Adding the input layer and the first hidden layer
model.add(Dense(6, activation='relu',input_dim = 11))

# Adding the second hidden layer (The real model contains many hidden layers)
model.add(Dense(6,activation='relu')) 
# Adding the output layer
model.add(Dense( 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
```

Then I used keras visualizer to get a visualization of the neural network without weights.

```py
# Compiling the ANN
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'Adamax', loss = 'binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
model_history=classifier.fit(X_train, y_train.to_numpy(), batch_size = 10, epochs = 100)
```

I want to print trained weights of the model for this kind of visualization. Is there any library or module that I can use for that? Any suggestion will be helpful. Here is the picture of the designed neural network without printing weights.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding TensorBoard (weight) histograms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42315202/understanding-tensorboard-weight-histograms)

Comment: @Mario Not the exact answer. The visualization should be with nodes and edges like with circles and arrows. But thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to print trained weights of the model to this kind of visualization. Is there any library or module that I can use for that?

**Option1: [deepreplay](/questions/tagged/deepreplay)**

There is a workaround in the form of package\module so-called [Deep Replay](https://github.com/dvgodoy/deepreplay#deep-replay) you can import as a library for resolving your problem.

Thanks to this package, you can visualize\animate and the most probably print trained weights using the following example:

```py
# install FFMPEG (to generate animations)
#!apt-get install ffmpeg

# install actual deepreplay package
#!pip install deepreplay

from keras.initializers import glorot_normal, glorot_uniform, he_normal, he_uniform
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import Sequential
from deepreplay.callbacks import ReplayData
from deepreplay.datasets.ball import load_data
from deepreplay.plot import compose_plots, compose_animations
from deepreplay.replay import Replay

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path'] = '/usr/bin/ffmpeg'

X, y = load_data(n_dims=10)

activation = 'relu'
initializer_name = 'he_uniform'
initializer = eval(initializer_name)(seed=13)
title = 'Activation: ReLU - Initializer: {}'.format(initializer_name)
group_name = 'relu_{}'.format(initializer_name)
filename = f'{group_name}_{initializer_name}_{activation}_weight_initializers.h5'

# Model builder function
def build_model(n_layers, input_dim, units, activation, initializer):
    if isinstance(units, list):
        assert len(units) == n_layers
    else:
        units = [units] * n_layers

    model = Sequential()
    # Adds first hidden layer with input_dim parameter
    model.add(Dense(units=units[0],
                    input_dim=input_dim,
                    activation=activation,
                    kernel_initializer=initializer,
                    name='h1'))

    # Adds remaining hidden layers
    for i in range(2, n_layers + 1):
        model.add(Dense(units=units[i-1],
                        activation=activation,
                        kernel_initializer=initializer,
                        name='h{}'.format(i)))

    # Adds output layer
    model.add(Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer=initializer, name='o'))
    # Compiles the model
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['acc'])
    return model


replaydata = ReplayData(X, y, filename=filename, group_name=group_name)

# Create the MLP model with 5 layers within 10 input neurons and 100 unists in hidden and output layers
model = build_model(n_layers=5, input_dim=10, units=100, activation=activation, initializer=initializer)

# fit the model over 10 epochs with batch size of 16
model.fit(X, y, epochs=10, batch_size=16, callbacks=[replaydata])

# Plot the results
replay = Replay(replay_filename=filename, group_name=group_name)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
ax_zvalues = plt.subplot2grid((2, 2), (0, 0))
ax_weights = plt.subplot2grid((2, 2), (0, 1))
ax_activations = plt.subplot2grid((2, 2), (1, 0))
ax_gradients = plt.subplot2grid((2, 2), (1, 1))

wv = replay.build_weights(ax_weights)
gv = replay.build_gradients(ax_gradients)

# Z-values
zv = replay.build_outputs(ax_zvalues, before_activation=True,
                          exclude_outputs=True, include_inputs=False)
# Activations
av = replay.build_outputs(ax_activations, exclude_outputs=True, include_inputs=False)

# Save plots
fig = compose_plots([zv, wv, av, gv], epoch=0, title=title)
fig.savefig('part2.png', format='png', dpi=120)

# Animate & save mp4
sample_anim = compose_animations([zv, wv, av, gv])
sample_anim.save('part2.mp4', dpi=120, fps=5)
```

visulize output results using violin plots over 10 epochs for simple:
[image: img]
So the top right subplot shows **Weights** change through the layers over ten epochs. The other subplots illustrate the performance of Z-values, Activation functions, and  Gradients changes.

**Note1:** if you are interested to interpret violin plots, please check these posts: [post1](https://towardsdatascience.com/violin-plots-explained-fb1d115e023d) , [post2](https://orange3.readthedocs.io/projects/orange-visual-programming/en/latest/widgets/visualize/violinplot.html), [post3](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2018/05/violin-and-density-plots-in-ggplot2/)

**Note2:** Please notice that the training process starts with some initializers, which can have different weighing at the beginning. The common initialization schemes are as follows:

- Random
- Xavier / Glorot
- He

By default, kernel initializer is `glorot_uniform` when you use [keras](/questions/tagged/keras) module [(reference)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54011300/10452700), but you can check this [post](https://towardsdatascience.com/hyper-parameters-in-action-part-ii-weight-initializers-35aee1a28404) and this paper [Understanding the difficulty of training deep feedforward neural networks](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v9/glorot10a/glorot10a.pdf) for further info. It is also possible to initialize weights in NN manually. You can check this [post](https://machinelearningmastery.com/weight-initialization-for-deep-learning-neural-networks/).

**Note3:** Recently, this package has a bug and can't be implemented in [Google Colab Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/), which is still an open issue; its [GH Repo](https://github.com/dvgodoy/deepreplay/issues/28) as well as post in [SoF](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70275940/edit). So it is better to try it on your own local machine, hopefully.

**Option2:[wandb](/questions/tagged/wandb)**

There is another ML-based tool, so-called [W&B (Weights and Biases)](https://github.com/wandb/client#weights-and-biases---) you can import as a library for resolving your problem.

once you sign-up and login into your account based on instructions, you can use this API to track and visualize all the pieces of your ML pipeline, including **Weights and Biases** and other parameters in your pipeline:

```py
import wandb
from wandb.keras import WandbCallback

# Step1: Initialize W&B run
wandb.init(project='project_name')

# 2. Save model inputs and hyperparameters
config = wandb.config
config.learning_rate = 0.01

# Model training code here ...
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
Optimiser=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate =0.001)
model.compile(loss=loss, optimizer=Optimiser, metrics=['accuracy'])
wandb.log({"loss": loss})

# Step 3: Add WandbCallback 
model.fit(X, y, epochs=10, batch_size=16, callbacks=[WandbCallback()])
```

once you run your `model`, you can check graph info in the *Model* section which is selected\shown on the left side with blue color:

[image: img]

hope this answer helps you out, and if it is so, you can accept it as an answer ✅.